# Problemas con validación de login PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login

Tengo el siguiente código para conexión a `BD` en `PHP`:
A continuación mi archivo de conexión:

```
<?php
$usuario = "usuario";
$password = "password";
$servidor = "host";
$basededatos = "nombredemibd";


$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
?>
```

Ahora les muestro el código de mi validación del `login`:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
require 'conexion.php';
sleep(2);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$clave = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clave']);


if ($nueva_consulta = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `crm`.`caso_servicios`,`crm`.`afiliados` WHERE `identificacion_afiliado` = ? AND `tipo_servicio_id` = 4 AND `caso_servicios`.`id` = ?")) {


    $nueva_consulta ->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $clave);
    $nueva_consulta->execute();
    $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();

    if ($resultado->num_rows == 1) {
        $datos = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo' => $datos['tipo_servicio_id']));


    } else {
        echo "no ingresaste";
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));

    }
    $nueva_consulta->close();

}

$mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

El error que tengo es que al enviar los datos desde el formulario de `login` hasta el archivo validador, la pagina queda en blanco. No se porque razón no esta ejecutando la consulta. Ya he probado la consulta con un código mas simple y me funciona, pero al añadir la seguridad del lado del servidor pasa esto.

Comment: En el archivo que crea la conexión a la base de datos, la conexión se llama `$conexion` y en el otro código se llama `$mysqli`, debes llamarlas igual para que funcione, o `$conexion` en ambos archivos o `$mysqli` en ambos. Otra cosa, si usas consultas preparadas, ya no necesitas escapar los datos con `real_escape_string`

Comment: Hice la modificación en el archivo, cambie en conexion.php la variable conexion por mysqli pero sigo con el mismo problema, al validar el login la pagina esta en blanco.

Comment: Hay eventualidades del código que no son cubiertas (tienes dos `if`  sin `else`). Te recomiendo que pongas los `else` con un `echo` indicando  por ejemplo:  *`No se cumplen las condiciones de servidor`*  y en el otro: *`No se encontraron datos en la consulta`*  Tu código es mudo en esos casos y si las condiciones no se cumplen no muestra nada, claro... por eso ves la página en blanco.

Comment: Estas sobreescribiendo la variable `$usuario` en tu código. Como no tienes un `try catch` no ves el problema, pero se muere porque tu `$usuario` no es el usuario de la base de datos si no el usuario que mete el user de tu web. Llama al `$usuario` que recibe el post `$user` y cambia donde aparezca `$usuario` por debajo del require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo este código, el cual controla todas las eventualidades, como he dicho ya en comentarios.

He optimizado algunas cosas como:

- Implementar en todo el estilo orientado a objetos. La conexión no implementaba ese estilo.
- Tirar de ciertas ventajas que ofrece la nueva API `mysqli`, como seleccionar la base de datos usando el constructor.
- El charset también es seteado cuando se crea la conexión. Tiene más utilidad ahí, que tener que hacerlo luego del `require`
- Evaluar con un ternario los datos del POST (ese control te faltaba).
- Poner los controles que faltaban. Incluso conviene probar si la conexión no es nula. Uno nunca sabe.
- Se recogerá en la variable `$mOutput` todo lo que ocurra en el código.

#### Archivo de conexión

```
<?php 
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $password = "password";
    $servidor = "host";
    $basededatos = "nombredemibd";
    
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

---

#### El otro archivo

```
<?php 

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        sleep(2); // what's that?
        $mUsuario = !empty( $_POST['usuario'] ) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
        $mClave = !empty( $_POST['clave'] )     ? $_POST['clave'] : NULL;
        if( $mUsuario && $mClave ) {
            require 'conexion.php';
            if($mysqli) {
                $sql="SELECT * FROM `crm`.`caso_servicios`,`crm`.`afiliados` WHERE `identificacion_afiliado` = ? AND `tipo_servicio_id` = 4 AND `caso_servicios`.`id` = ?";
                if ($nueva_consulta = $mysqli -> prepare($sql)) {
                    $nueva_consulta ->bind_param('ss', $,mUsuario, $mClave);
                    $nueva_consulta->execute();
                    $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();
                    if ($resultado->num_rows == 1) {
                        $datos = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                        $mOutPut=json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo' => $datos['tipo_servicio_id']));
                    } else {
                        $mOutPut=json_encode(array('error' => true));
                    }
                    $nueva_consulta->close();
                }
                $mysqli->close(); 
            } else {
                $mOutPut="No hay conexión";
            }
        } else {
            $mOutPut="No se postearon datos válidos";
        }
    } else {
        $mOutPut="Variables del tipo SERVER inválidas";
    }
    echo $mOutput;
?>
```

Estamos ante un código que hablará, pase lo que pase.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funciono perfectamente!